# How to upload on Dropbox Camera Capture image with Watermark without Compress (Keep Orignal Quality) in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, camera, dropbox

1. I am using this code right now but its destroy image quality.
2. I have issue regarding blur image

```
if (requestCode == IMAGE_REQUEST_CODE) {
        // Make sure the request was successful
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        //    kkkk(data.getData());
            picture = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");//this




// I pass bitmap to function to get watermark

   result = mark(picture , sh.getString("BARCODE", null), 10, 50,R.color.colorPrimaryDark,              200, 30, false);

// now i need a file to upload image on dropbox
file = storeImage(result);


}

// here is my function 

private File storeImage(Bitmap image) {


    File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();


    if (pictureFile == null) {
        Log.d("",
                "Error creating media file, check storage permissions: ");//    e.getMessage());
        return null;

    }

    try {
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);

        image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,55, fos);
            fos.flush();

        fos.close();


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        Log.d("", "File not found: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.d("", "Error accessing file: " + e.getMessage());
    }

    return pictureFile;
    }

   private File getOutputMediaFile() {
    // To be safe, you should check that the SDCard is mounted
    // using Environment.getExternalStorageState() before doing this.
    File mediaStorageDir = new    File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
            + "/Android/data/"
            + getApplicationContext().getPackageName()
            + "/Files");


    // This location works best if you want the created images to be shared
    // between applications and persist after your app has been uninstalled.

    // Create the storage directory if it does not exist
    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("ddMMyyyy_HHmmss").format(new Date());
    File mediaFile;
    increase++;
    String mImageName = sh.getString("BARCODE", null) + "_" + timeStamp +  ".jpg";
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator +  mImageName);
    return mediaFile;

}


</i>
 }
```

Comment: You took the thumbnaiil of the original picture. Thats why the quality is bad. Setup your intent differently so you get an uri to the original file.

Comment: I didn't understand how setup intent differently ,I am just get bitmap on Camera OK button, and I need a file to upload it .

Comment: Well google a bit. Code has been posted a hundred times here.

Comment: i am stuck here ,I applied many code many time , I think i am wrong somewhere, can you send me the link